# How do I put multiple HyperlinkButtons on a row in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a number of tags (string) in a JSON-formatted stream (resultFromServer) that I put into a list (articleTagList):

```
if (resultFromServer.tag != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < resultFromServer.tag.Length; i++)
    {
        articleTagList.Add(resultFromServer.tag[i]);
    }

    listboxArticleTags.Items.Clear();
    listboxArticleTags.ItemsSource = articleTagList;
}
```

The listboxArticleTags listbox is using the following data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myArticleTagsTemplate">
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Tag" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem with this is that all tags/HyperlinkButtons end up on one line each:

```
[Code]
[Example]
[Silverlight]
```

I want them on a single row:

```
[Code] [Example] [Silverlight]
```

This is for a WP7 app which I'm sure limits my options but is this at all possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: In SL generally you would change the actual *listbox template* so that its inner container is horizontally orientated. I imaging that is still possible for WP7 (although I have not tried it yet myself). The listbox template is independent of the item template so you need to do both.

Comment: Well, I apply the DataTemplate above to the listbox:

`<ListBox x:Name="listboxArticleTags" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myArticleTagsTemplate}"/>`

Comment: Stop changing the data template, as that is the per item template and not the container, change the ItemsPanelTemplate as Oliver Weichhold suggests.

Answer (score 1):

This works in regular SL and should also work on the phone. I would also consider switching to ItemsControl instead of ListBox because I don't think that you actually need support for selections in this case.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: For WP7, we use a ListBox for all ItemsControl-like display, as there's no ListView.

Comment: Well, I added the Orientation="Horizontal" to my DataTemplate but it didn't do any difference. I don't want to use inline templates like the one you suggest above.